# GitHub 'your credentials may be out of date' can't clone

Tags: github, repository

I have tried logging out and in, changing password and non work.
I also downloaded the project as zip and put it in the folder. But I can't 'find' it on github client for windows and I cannot clone it then it tells me the project already exist. But I can't open the repository on github for windows. I have deleted Github for windows and re-installed it. I've removed the SSH on github.com so it would make new keys. None work. Any suggestions?

I am getting this error:
http://snag.gy/eHlqj.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So no specific reason at all but;

1. It was almost 5 months that I was part of this private project. 5 of us are committing almost every day for the past 5 months. Only I had this problem so far.
2. What helped:

   - Uninstall github
   - use something like ccleaner to clean your pc and registry
   - remove %AppData%\GitHub manually
   - remove %LocalAppData%\GitHub manually
   - restart
   - go to www.github.com in your account and remove the SSH key's.
   - install github client and login
   - done, it should work now

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is a problem of web credentials, have you tried with another browser? or to clear the cache of Chrome?

Comment: I removed everything with Ccleaner. Tried it nothing. I also used a fresh new account and still the same error.

Comment: i tried to go in the page that you have linked in a pic but not exist i have found only 1 projet https://github.com/onwezen ,is it possible that other project is a private project. Is a your own user onwezen?

Comment: The project is private, but both of my accounts are invited and I can see the project on Github.com. I just can't clone it

Comment: I've never used private projects on github but it is possible that the credentials expire in a year for safety .. if you know the owner you can ask him if he can check the credentials ...